# Voice chat with Google talk users

Tags: windows-7, google-talk, xmpp, voice-chat

Is there any app that support Audio chat with Google talk users? 
Indeed I am looking for a replacement for GoogleTakl and Google Video browser plug-in?

My main concern is audio and video support is a bonus!

**Update:** I found this table too: http://www.google.com/talk/otherclients.html

It show clients that do not support audio chat to google talk users. (It's may be not up to date)

Comment: What's wrong with Google Talk or Google voice and video chat?

Comment: @harrymc Clearly Google voice and video is web-based and you need open browser to use it. Google talk do not provide invisible mode, grouping and a lot more missed features.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/)

It's a audio/video and chat application written in Java, and based on XMPP

Comment: I tried it. It is an innovative and exiting program, but its interaction with Google Talk is not stable.

Comment: You can also try [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im) or [Psi](http://psi-im.org), but I'm not sure about video chat support.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia's Google Talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk) :

> Google Talk uses extensions to [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) for voice/video signaling and
>   peer-to-peer communication. As of August 2012, Google Talk’s
>   implementation differs slightly from the draft XMPP [Jingle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_%28protocol%29)
>   specifications. However, Google Talk is in the process of being
>   updated to be in [full compliance](https://developers.google.com/talk/open_communications) with the Jingle specifications.

Wikipedia also contains a better and more up-to-date [comparison chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients#XMPP-related_features) for
XMPP-related features of instant messaging clients :

[image]

Without any experience with them, the following clients look like they support
both voice and video, so are maybe worth looking into :

[Gajim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gajim)
[Jitsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitsi)
[Kopete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopete)

Comment: Jitsi was already mentioned by @rhon. Just to remark that its unstable connection to Google Talk may be the fault of Google not (yet?) fully implementing the Jingle standard, so it's worthwhile trying other clients to see if it's the same with them.

Comment: Well, the list contains all the well-known clients. If none of them works well, then it's probably the fault of Google.

Answer (score 0):

[Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) will do the job for you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: @slm: Given that the link is to the Pidgin home page, it can never break, unless the product was discontinued and then it should break ....

Comment: @ harrymc, understand, and I would tend to agree, but a little more than a link would be nice 8-). Not trying to scare mecyborg away, just trying to keep the quality of the site high. Without mentioning what Pidgin is, if the link changes/goes away then mecyborg's answer becomes just cruft.

Comment: hey its just fine